# How to bind data from dropdown list in asp.net 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have 2 models name BTBNewLien2 & BuyerSelectList. Now I want to bind "BuyerSelectList" data at the BTBNewLien2 model. How can I do that? All the necessary codes are given below:  My Question is where should I use ViewBag for Binding Data? I can create all the related views. I just need help with the Controller.

BTBNewLien2.cs Model:

```
public class BTBNewLien2
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Buyer")]
        public int BuyerSelectListId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BuyerSelectListId")]
        [ValidateNever]
        public BuyerSelectList BuyerSelectList { get; set; }
    }
```

BuyerSelectList.cs Model :

```
public class BuyerSelectList
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("BUYER")]
        public string Buyer { get; set; }
    }
```

BTBNewLien2Controller :

```
public class BTBNewLien2Controller : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public BTBNewLien2Controller(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<BTBNewLien2> objBTBNewLienList = _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.GetAll();
            return View(objBTBNewLienList);
        }
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(BTBNewLien2 obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.Add(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Row Created Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var objBTBNewLienList = _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (objBTBNewLienList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(objBTBNewLienList);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(BTBNewLien2 obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.Update(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Row Edited Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var objBTBNewLienList = _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (objBTBNewLienList == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(objBTBNewLienList);
        }
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeletePOST(int? id)
        {
            var obj = _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _unitOfWork.BTBNewLien2.Remove(obj);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            TempData["success"] = "Row Deleted Successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

BTBNewLien2Repository:

```
public class BTBNewLien2Repository : Repository<BTBNewLien2>, IBTBNewLien2Repository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public BTBNewLien2Repository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void Update(BTBNewLien2 obj)
        {
            var objFromDb = _db.BTBNewLien2.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == obj.Id);
            if (objFromDb != null)
            {
                objFromDb.BuyerSelectListId = obj.BuyerSelectListId;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to do it with any of your controller action methods (wherever is your requirement is there). Describe your question in a more proper way. so that anyone can understand.

Comment: Thanks @Shibu for the replay. I want to to add Buyer data from BuyerselectList Model at BTBNewLien2 create view. I have given that two models and also BTBNewLien2 Controller . Now i need to know where are the functionalities that i should add in the BTBNewLien2 controller for binding BuyerSelectList property into BTBNewLien2 create method?

Comment: When you load view, you can create a dropdownlist about DropdownList in get method. You can refer to [this](https://www.compilemode.com/2021/06/dropdown-list-in-asp-net-core-mvc.html)